# When Word 2010 has an "unspecified error", the part and line number are shown. How can I display this info in Word 2019?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

In Word 2010, if there is an error in the OOXML when you try to open a file there is a detailed error message, like so:

[image]

Word 2019 doesn't provide the same error details. I only get this:

[image]

Is there a way to have Word 2019 display the detailed error messages that were displayed in Word 2010?

Comment: I've added a bounty. This question was down voted, but no explanation was given. This is an issue I have struggled with and I thought it was clear what I am asking. But if anyone can suggest improvements to the question please let me know! Desperate for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Opening it with the [Open XML SDK Productivity Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) will give you this. Is that sufficient?

Comment: I tried it and no, this doesn't work. For a simple case it says the document part is valid in a file that won't open in Word. Same file in Word 2010 provides the line number of the error.

Comment: Is your question specific to that document? Or is it just one of your cases? I tested this with a mangled document.xml, and it provided the line and column, so our test cases must differ.

Comment: That was just a simple example. As well, it will not open OOXML files at all.